# ExcelRobot - Robot Framework Ride - Import Issue

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I have managed to import the `ExcelRobot` library into Ride and everything look normal since the name didnt got in red.
[image]

When I go to the Test Case and call the keyword `Open Excel`, it shows the keyword is available.
[image]

However, when I ran the Test Case, I got the error `Importing test library 'ExcelRobot' failed: ImportError: No module named ExcelRobot`

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the library that you are going to use. But I have used "ExcelLibrary" in my test suite and its perfectly working.

1. Step 01: pip install robotframework-excellibrary
2. Step 02: Check the library in your python path (Ex. C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ExcelLibrary)
3. Step 03: Import the library in your test

Example code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           ExcelLibrary
Library           String

*** Variables ***
${ExcelLocation}    ExcelTestNumbers.xls
${ExcelOutputLocation}    ExcelTestNumbersOutput.xls
${ExcelSheetName}    Sheet1

*** Test Cases ***
NumberRotation
    NumberRotation

*** Keywords ***
NumberRotation
    ExcelLibrary.Open Excel    ${ExcelLocation}
    ${ExcelRowCount}    ExcelLibrary.Get Row Count    ${ExcelSheetName}
    Log to console    Excel_Row_Count_${ExcelRowCount}
    : FOR    ${LoopCycle}    IN RANGE    ${ExcelRowCount}
    \    Log to console    Loop_Rotation_${LoopCycle}
    \    ${CurrentProcessingNumber}=    ExcelLibrary.Read Cell Data By Coordinates    ${ExcelSheetName}    0    ${LoopCycle}
    \    Log to console    CurrentProcessingNumber_${CurrentProcessingNumber}
    \    ExcelLibrary.Put String to Cell    ${ExcelSheetName}    1    ${LoopCycle}    ExcelSave${LoopCycle}
    \    Save Excel    ${ExcelOutputLocation}
    \    Log to console    Saved
    \    ...    ELSE    NumberInvalid
```

ExcelLibrary Keywords: http://navinet.github.io/robotframework-excellibrary/ExcelLibrary-KeywordDocumentation.html

Hope this helps.

cheers.

Comment: I too have used this library in my testings. I too think to import it's better to use ExcelLibrary. I tried to find keyword documentation of ExcelRobot but could not.

Comment: Thank you for your support @Nipuna & @Muditha, I'm been struggling to make`ExcelLibrary` work, but I always get import issue on Ride (red), the version I have installed is 0.0.2. on my python 2.7, I have also checked the folder `Lib\site-packages` and the folder is there, I dont know if there ia any library which I'm having conflict with, maybe some pre requisites in order to work properly is not been respected.

Comment: Since I couldnt managed to use `ExcelLibrary`, I tried the `robotexcel` librayry, regarding the documentation, I used the link `https://zero-88.github.io/robotframework-excel/docs/ExcelRobot.html` . Any idea what can be wrong with any of the libraries? Thanks

Comment: I'm using Robot Framework 3.2.1 (Python 2.7.11 on win32), RIDE 1.7.4.2 running on Python 2.7.11. Actually Robotframework hardest part is to setup the environment. Anyway with my setup ExcelLibrary should work.

Answer (score 2):

RIDE includes robotframework 3.1.2 as an internal library, so it can process the keywords documentation, and even do its job as an Editor in systems without robotframework installed. This strategy also allows to have RIDE 1.7.4.2 installed in Python 2.7 but run `robot` installed on Python 3.

The error you report, would fall on this scenario, where the library import is correctly detected, but not at execution time.

RIDE's TestRunner (the Run tab), prepares the execution arguments to `robot` and calls it, just like from a command window, shell or terminal. The first `robot` found by the PATH environment variable, is the one that is run.

See Tools->RIDE Log the line mentioning what `robot` was found, and also the TestRunner message.